# Raspberry Pi Python Error

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi

I tried to install distribute or setuptools which has to be done prior to installing pip on the Raspberry Pi.

The command used was `$ curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python`

However I got the following error. I can copy past the entire terminal script if requested.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-2082.pth'
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How about trying to ask here instead? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never using raspberry pi. But from the log can be seen it complain about cannot have permission to modify python package directory. You have to run pip install using root privilege.

Comment: did you add the sudo directly before the `python`, after the pipe? Otherwise, only the download with curl will have root-privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on what ever operating system you have but one that is specifically Linux based like raspbian you should open up terminal and type in chmod +x **file path here**. Also for this to work you should be inside where ever the file is stored when you run chmod +x etc... /Desktop/python/ for example would work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python command
```

some permisssions problem are resolved like this. I'm not sure if this works.